# Customer Portal and SOQL query optimization

Tags: soql, indexing, custom-index

We have a customer portal which has sharing set by Account i.e. Record level security by granting access to portal users where their Account matches the Account associated with the record.

I was under impression that , SF adds filter for account to any SOQL query from custom portal which has account sharing set i.e. it adds filter ( AND Account__c = '001xxxxxxx' ) to any query from customer portal based on account of the logged in user.

When I login as portal user and look at debug logs for SOQL query being executed I don't see any filter added ( AND Account__c = '001xxxxxxx' ) .

Does this mean any SOQL query fired from customer portal with sharing set as account may not be selective ?
e.g. a query on custom object,

```
 select Name from MyCustObj__c where Status__c= 'Approved'
```

will not be selective if there is no custom index on Status__c field ?

Any insight on this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

SF doesn't know in advance what your sharing model for your portal is going to be. If you're running this query from a controller or other code, then it's your responsibility to make it more selective.